# iOS - iPhone should serve as REST Server

Tags: web-services, json, ios, apache

I'd like to implement a server like behaviour on iOS. For internal communication in a hybrid app (partly native/partly web), I'd like to serve Data from the native backend to the JavaScript based front-end.
I was thinking about a REST solution. Doing some google ground work, I found many HTTP-Servers for iOS like mongoose etc.

Has anybody implemented a REST-Server or something like this? I'm looking for a good starting point here.

Thank in advance
Chris

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [REST kit](http://restkit.org) in combination with [CocoaHTTPServer](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver). It works quite well. Plus you can announce your service in the LAN via Bonjour.

On Android we are using [i-Jetty](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/) and regular Java servlets in combination with [FlexJSON](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net). That works very well. We used this on low-budget devices and had no problem.

Comment: Thx guys, I'll have a look on this very soon! Looks great so far.